# A finite group G acts freely on a simply connected manifold M

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

If a finite group G acts freely on a simply connected manifold M,Is the fundamental group $\pi_1(M/G,x_0)$ isomorhphic to G? If it is true,how to prove it?

Comment: Would $M$ be a universal cover space of $M/G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a free action of finite group on  Hausdorff space is a covering space action. Then the quotient map from M to M/G is normal covering map and G is isomorphic to fundamental group of M/G, since M is simply connected.

Comment: What is the definition of normal covering map?I don't understand "G is isomorphic to fundamental group of M/G, since M is simply connected".Wolud you mind explaining it in detail?

Answer (score 2):

If the action of $G$ is free, then it is also proper, so $M/G$ is a manifold, moreover it is a covering map and a Serre fibration, apply the exact sequence:

$1\rightarrow \pi_1(M)=1\rightarrow\pi_1(M/G)\rightarrow\pi_0(G)\rightarrow 1$.

Answer (score 1):

[image: you see the proposition 1.40 in Hatcher,s Book Algebraic topology]
This is the property of covering space action.

Comment: I have another quesion,if the manifold is not simply connected,does the quotient map $M\rightarrow M/G$ have the path lifting property and homotopy lfting property?

Comment: Here I have not used the homotopy lifting property